# Why is not the free list sorted?

Tags: c, data-structures, malloc, free

I study malloc, sbrk and free list management. Now I wonder why the free list isn't sorted in some way, it seems that it could benefit from being a search tree instead of a plain linked list. The way it looks in the [book](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) I'm reading is just a list with free chunks of memory of arbitrary sizes. It seems trivial that if we keep the list sorted then the first fit will also be the best fit.

I'm certain this has been considered before but why isn't it done?

Comment: What allocator are you asking about. In C it is not specified how the free store is implemented, just that the functions work

Comment: @M.M I think that I mean `ptmalloc3` but I'm not sure that I understand.

Comment: The last sentence of paragraph 3 in [section 17.1](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-freespace.pdf): _Of course, this data structure need not be a list per se, but just some kind of data structure to track free space._ So you could very well use a tree if you wished; a linked list is simply easier to code for illustrating the concept, especially since you don't have `malloc` to help with allocation of the nodes of the list/tree.

Comment: If your implementation does not sort free list, it probably does not do it for a perfectly good reason: in real life the benefits of ultra-fast list element addition outweigh the benefits of sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the algorithms presented in that section mostly aim at reducing fragmentation and search cost. Under the section "Other Ideas" he mentions his reasoning when presenting first fit, best fit, worst fit etc...

> ```
> One major problem with many of the approaches described above is their
> lack of scaling. Specifically, searching lists can be quite slow. Thus,
> advanced allocators use more complex data structures to address these
> costs, trading simplicity for performance. Examples include balanced binary
> trees, splay trees, or partially-ordered trees [W+95].
> ```

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-freespace.pdf